# when addressing to user in comments - @user as it is or without spaces?? example @Abcd E F or @AbcdEF?

Tags: support, user-accounts, users, user-communication

I am confused while addressing the user in comments..
if the user name for example "Abcd E F"

How do I address it, @Abcd E F or @AbcdEF ??

Comment: "I observed when there are spaces in user name, with tab it is not possible to auto fill." - I don't think this is correct. If user is actually *ping-able* by you, it should suggest the user (it should suggest `@AbcdEF`).

Comment: yes @pomsky.... i have tested it on the actual users question with tab. his user name is `Abcd E F` and i tried `Abcd tab` may be thats the cause it did not suggest any because i think its not necessary. Even if i specify `@Abcd E F + my comment` system will ignore in such case as `me and Abcd E F ` are in discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020) on [How do comment @replies work? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/)

> Spaces are removed *from the display names* for matching purposes. So to match Peter Smith you may use *@pet*, *@peter*, *@peters*, or *@petersmith*.  The last two are useful if Peter Jones is also participating, who can then be distinguished using *@peterj*. However, no spaces are allowed in the *@name* itself. Like to notify P Smith, one must use *@psm* or *@psmith*. (Here *@P Smith* would be handled as just *@P*, which is too short.) Single quotes, dots, dashes and underscores should [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies/51913#51913) be removed.

So, any combination of greater than three alphabets starting with first name will notify user "Abcd E F", if he made any comment previously on the same post  and if there is no conflicting username participating. It's better to use @AbcdEF to notify "Abcd E F", to avoid any kind of conflicts. In short, spaces can be neglected while writing the full name.

Comment: "So, "@Abcd E F" will notify user "**Abcd**", if he made..." - I don't think is completely correct as per the answer posted in Meta SE. If there is no conflict, then it should indeed notify user '**Abcd E F**' (as the answer claims 'Peter Smith' can be notified using `@peters`). However, if there's another participant `@Abcd X Y`, then there might be an issue.

Comment: @pomsky I've edited the post. Now I hope it's correct. :)

Comment: "... greater than three alphabets starting with first name will notify user "Abcd E F", if he made any comment previously on the same post." *and if there is no conflicting username participating* ;-)

Comment: @pomsky Added that too :)